# ASP.NET Web application Graphic Doesnt Show My Data Values

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hello Friends I've got a project from my intership that i had datas in json file i have to put in to c# then compare them in front end side. Ive done some parts of it but with the graphical things i dont know anything so im chatting with chatgpt for 4 days

When i select my datas from table then select the time like 1month,3month,6month etc. then press the button it should be a graphic that compares them by the value of that timeline .But when i press button the graphical thing shows up and i can see data names and they random colors but they never show up in graphical i see only in graphic table info and when i check console in web, jsondata and jsondatalist look like working but selectedData 0:undefined 1:undefined it says. If anyone can help me i would be so glad. Thank you for your time all.

This is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Fon.Models
{
    public class Fonlar
    {
            public string Fon_Kodu { get; set; }
            public string Fon_Adı { get; set; }
            public string Ay1 { get; set; }
            public string Ay3 { get; set; }
            public string Ay6 { get; set; }
            public string Yilbasi { get; set; }
            public string Yil1 { get; set; }
            public string Yil3 { get; set; }
            public string Yil5 { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, List<int>> Fon_Verileri { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my Controller's ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult Grafiksel()
        {
            string jsonFilePath = @"C:\Users\arda\source\repos\Fon\Fon\JsonFon\fon_analiz.json";
            string jsonContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
            List<Fonlar> fonlarList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Fonlar>>(jsonContent);

            ViewBag.JsonLabels = new List<string> { "Ay1", "Ay3", "Ay6", "Yilbasi", "Yil1", "Yil3", "Yil5" };
            ViewBag.JsonDataList = JsonSerializer.Serialize(fonlarList);

            return View(fonlarList);
        }
```

And this is my View

```
    @model List<Fon.Models.Fonlar>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grafik Karşılaştırma</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/x-icon;,">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 600px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        tr.first {
            background-color: #009f05;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: white;
        }

        tr.second {
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 2px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 1200px;
        }

        tr.second:hover {
            background-color: #00ff0f;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="jsonData" data-values="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.JsonDataList))" style="display: none;"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/styles.css">
    <div class="navbar-container">
        <!--style.css-->
        <nav>
            <img src="~/Content/images/Gedik_Yatirim.png" alt="logo" class="logo" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Anasayfa", "Home")">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Fonlar</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Grafiksel", "Home")">Grafik Karşılaştırma</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Hakkimizda", "Home")">Hakkımızda</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="table2-container" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="first">
                    <th class="Fon_Kodu">
                        Fon Kodu
                        <button class="Fon_Kodu" onclick="sortTable('Fon_Kodu')">↕</button>
                    </th>
                    <th class="Fon_Adı">
                        Fon Adı
                        <button class="Fon_Adı" onclick="sortTable('Fon_Adı')">↕</button>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var fon in Model)
            {
                <tr class="second">
                    <td class="Fon_Kodu">@fon.Fon_Kodu</td>
                    <td class="Fon_Adı">@fon.Fon_Adı</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFon" value="@fon.Fon_Adı" class="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="display: none;" id="fonData_@Model.IndexOf(fon)">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonDataList[Model.IndexOf(fon)])</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        <div class="search2-container">
            <label for="searchBox2">Arama :</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox2" onkeyup="searchTable()" placeholder="Metin Girin">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
            <label for="timeOptions">Zaman Aralığı:</label>
            <select id="timeOptions" class="time-dropdown">
                <option value="Ay1">1 Ay</option>
                <option value="Ay3">3 Ay</option>
                <option value="Ay6">6 Ay</option>
                <option value="Yilbasi">Yılbaşı</option>
                <option value="Yil1">1 Yıl</option>
                <option value="Yil3">3 Yıl</option>
                <option value="Yil5">5 Yıl</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="grafik" onclick="updateChart()">Seç</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
        var myChart = null;
        var sortOrder = {
            Fon_Kodu: 1,
            Fon_Adı: 1,
            Ay1: 1,
            Ay3: 1,
            Ay6: 1,
            Yilbasi: 1,
            Yil1: 1,
            Yil3: 1,
            Yil5: 1,
        };
        var jsonDataList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.JsonDataList));
        var labels = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.JsonLabels));
        var selectedData = [];
        var selectedFons = [];
        

        function sortTable(columnName) {
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
            table = document.querySelector(".table2-container");
            switching = true;
            while (switching) {
                switching = false;
                rows = table.querySelectorAll(".second");
                for (i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    x = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td")[Object.keys(sortOrder).indexOf(columnName)].textContent;
                    y = rows[i + 1].querySelectorAll("td")[Object.keys(sortOrder).indexOf(columnName)].textContent;
                    if (sortOrder[columnName] === 1 ? turkishCompare(x, y) > 0 : turkishCompare(x, y) < 0) {
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
            sortOrder[columnName] *= -1;
        }
        function turkishCompare(a, b) {
            return a.localeCompare(b, "tr", { sensitivity: "base" });
        }
        function searchTable() {
            var input = document.getElementById("searchBox2");
            var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var headerRow = table.querySelector("thead tr");

            var matchingRows = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                var found = false;

                for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                    var txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;

                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found) {
                    matchingRows.push(tr[i]);
                }
            }

            matchingRows.sort(function (a, b) {
                var textA = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                var textB = b.textContent || b.innerText;
                return textA.localeCompare(textB, "tr", { sensitivity: "base" });
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            matchingRows.forEach(function (row) {
                row.style.display = "";
            });

            headerRow.style.display = "";
        }
        /******************************* */
        console.log("Jsondatalist geliyo mu", jsonDataList);

        function updateChartData(selectedFons, selectedData, selectedTimeRange) {
            if (myChart) {
                myChart.destroy();
            }
            var datasets = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < selectedFons.length; i++) {
                datasets.push({
                    label: selectedFons[i],
                    data: selectedData[i],
                    backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
                    borderWidth: 1
                });
            }

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: datasets
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function updateChart() {
    selectedFons = [];
    selectedData = [];
    var selectedTimeRange = document.getElementById("timeOptions").value;

    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selectedFon"]:checked');
    var jsonData = jsonDataList;

    checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        selectedFons.push(checkbox.value);
        var index = Array.from(checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.children).indexOf(checkbox.parentNode);
        var filteredData = jsonData[index][selectedTimeRange]; // Buradaki değişiklik
        selectedData.push(filteredData);
    });

    console.log("Seçilen fonlar:", selectedFons);
    console.log("Seçilen veriler:", selectedData);
    console.log("secilen saat aralığı", selectedTimeRange);

    updateChartData(selectedFons, selectedData, selectedTimeRange);
}

        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            var color = "#";
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```